# Bind Datepicker with the calculated date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker. It should allow me to set date to calculated date.

Calculated date is of the form

`myNewDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

ex: Sat Oct 11 2014 20:45:41 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

However, I am not able to bind this date to the datepicker.

`$(".myTestbox").datepicker('setDate', myNewDate);`

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: @ADASein I have already set that property as:     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Inside the datepicker, which event will contain calculated myNewDate?

Answer (score 0):

Two steps: 
Create the datepicker and then set the date:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gm11taz/

```
$("#dp").datepicker().datepicker('setDate',new Date(2013, 0, 1, 8, 15));
```

Or use the `defaultDate` option:

```
$("#dp").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 8, 15) });
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate